# Delphi localize VCL program with built in tool

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

While in C# it's pretty easy, in Delphi it seems that it's not. I have this test project in french:

[image]

And I have added italian and english as languages in this part of the IDE following the steps:

[image]

I've followed the steps I've found in the doc about resource dlls. Now I have this

[image]

But now, how do I translate the caption of the buttons? I haven't found useful info in the documentation, it seemed pretty confusing to me.

---

I have done the following with ITA

[image]

And ENG

[image]

But in Project > Languages I set ITALIAN as active but still I see everything in english. Am I missing something?

I already know that there are localization tools like TsiLang, TLanguages, DKLang and so (I already rely on them) but I wanted to try this built in feature.

Comment: I have understood it so that the IDE always shows the project with the "base" resource. With the setting in "Project - Languages - Set active" you can select the language to use when running under the IDE, to check what it looks like. After the project is deployed, you switch the language e.g. dynamically using the method [shown here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Dynamic_Switching_of_Resource_DLLs)

Comment: The methods referred to in the documentation I linked to in my previous comment, are in a unit called `reinit.pas` which was rather hard to find. The latest I found was in conjunction with a `RichEdit` sample from Delphi XE6. On my installation it was in path: `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Samples\Object Pascal\VCL\RichEdit`. Note I have never used or even tried this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to compile and build the whole group not just the project, you can find this under:

```
Project > Compile All Projects
Project > Build All Projects
```

Then run your project again, it should run the language you have been set as Active